# Removing a search help from a field

Tags: abap, sap-data-dictionary

I am getting the following error:
Search field ZEMPLOY01-CARRIER not contained in search help attachment.

A search help ZEMPLOY_ESH is attached to the table field: ZEMPLOY01-CARRIER.

However, as i am getting this error i want to remove the search help from the table's field. As you can see from the attachement, the search help is greyed out and won't allow me to remove the search help.

Attaching search help to screen field:

[image]

[image]

search help entry Not editable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate to the dialog shown in the first picture, then press the Trash Can button at the bottom of the dialog.